# How to keep google-chrome from buffering

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, mime-types

I have a situation where I am calling a js function when a button is clicked in a php page, a hidden dialog is displayed and some data is painted in the dialog prior to issuing a series of synchronous ajax calls which generate SQL statements server-side. This process may be repeated in a loop which is the reason for the synchronous ajax as the loop would need to be interrupted should the ajax call return an error of some kind.

My problem is that Chrome will not display the data prior to the ajax call whereas firefox will. I've tried setting the contentType method of the jqXHR Object to "application/octet-stream" but no luck.

Here's the ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
    async : false,
    url : "url",
    method : "GET", // redudntant, GET is the default
    dataType : "text",
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream;");
    },
    success : function(data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    // do stuff with error
});
```

Comment: *This process may be repeated in a loop which is the reason for the synchronous ajax as the loop would need to be interrupted should the ajax call return an error of some kind.* Huh? Asynchronous calls can be aborted and can have `error` callbacks.

Comment: Right, but as I indicate the ajax call must return its data before the loop is repeated. Not only that but the user has no idea what's happening because chrome is not allowing anything to display. The server-side process can take some time to complete so I need to show something otherwise he'll think it's frozen. Firefox doesn't do that. Anything I add to a div's innerHTML appears instantly.

Comment: So, don't use a loop at all. Use a regular asynchronous AJAX call and separate the loop code into its own function. Then, in the success callback, call the function that used to be the loop body. Then, the browser won't become unresponsive and you won't perform the next task until the previous one is done.

Comment: Good advice but it doesn't answer the main point of the question: why is chrome behaving differently from firefox? Is it due to buffering (I read somewhere that chrome buffers 1K before displaying) and if so how can that be overcome? I'd like an answer to that before I restructure my logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer to my original question but given that nobody was able to answer it or even give me advice or point me in the right direction I reworked my code completely to eliminate client-side code with reliance on ajax for server-side processing. My solution relies almost entirely on server-side code with minimal client-side limited to messaging and informational visuals and no ajax. The fact that no solution was forthcoming from the community is a source of great disappointment as I've come to rely on stackoverflow for advice and examples. It begs the question: was it that nobody had the answer or that it was deemed answered?